# Pandas - Count consecutive rows greater than zero on the group level

Tags: python, r, pandas

I would like to translate this R code into Python's pandas:

```
gg <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b')
val <- c(-2, 2, -1, 2, 3, 3, -7, 5, 6, 2, 8)
df = data.table(gg=gg, val=val)
df[, gg_count := seq(.N), by = gg]
df[, counter := gg_count - na.locf(ifelse(val <= 0, gg_count, NA), na.rm=F), by=gg]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  gg val gg_count counter???
   a  -2        1       0
   a   2        2       1
   b  -1        1       0
   a   2        3       2
   b   3        2       1
   b   3        3       2
   a  -7        4       0
   a   5        5       1
   a   6        6       2
   a   2        7       3
   b   8        4       3
```

Basically, I have columns "gg" and "val" and need to get to the column "counter". In R, I used also helper column "gg_count".

"counter" column, as you can see in the example, counts how many consecutive rows have "val" greater than zero. When negative number pops up, we reset the counter and start counting again. Everything needs to be done on a group level using column "gg".

Comment: would be great to provide an input pandas DataFrame and the matching expected output

Comment: @I'mahdi no, but the question is "how to convert R code into python pandas", so the question is clearly missing python details but still required the python/pandas tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
g = df['val'].le(0).groupby(df['gg']).cumsum() # get groups between negative numbers
df['val'].gt(0).groupby([df['gg'], g]).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
0     0
1     1
2     0
3     2
4     1
5     2
6     0
7     1
8     2
9     3
10    3
Name: val, dtype: int64
```